# background no funciona y tampoco sale error

Tags: javascript, ionic

Buen dia tengo una función que se ejecuta en el constructor  y lo activo con

```
background:
  enviarDatingos(nMinuto){
    //let nDuracion = 1000*60*nMinuto;
    let nDuracion = 1000*nMinuto;

    //console.log(this.backgroundMode.enable());
    // Empezamos a enviar dato de acuerdo al parametro nMinutos
    setInterval(() => {
       //Aqui ejecutamos el servicio
       //console.log(this.contador);
      this.backgroundMode.enable();
       this.contador++;
    },nDuracion);
  }
```

Luego tengo otra para parar:

```
parar(){

    this.backgroundMode.disable();

  }
```

En el navegador no funciona por cordova, instalé en el dispositivo tampoco funciona, no sale ningún error, alguien sabe ¿el por qué no funciona esa librería nativa?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver con los siguientes metodos y utilizando setInterval:

```
count:number = 0;
 counter:number;
 start(){
        if (this.counter) clearInterval(this.counter);
    this.counter = setInterval(() => {
      //acas se ejecuta el servicio 
       this.count++;
       console.log(this.count);
      },2000);
 }
stop(){
if (this.counter) clearInterval(this.counter);
    this.count = 0;
}
```

Y esto se implementan en el constructor y en las siguientes funciones de la pagina inicial:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.stop();

  }
  ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.start();
  }
```